# WP Meta Query 'compare' '<=' perform' '=' instead

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I seem to be having a little issue with the meta query within the functions.php file... I'm trying to perform a query on a numerical value with the postmeta table.

Here is the query:

```
$query->set('meta_key', 'salary_max');
$query->set('meta_value', $_GET['slide']);
$query->set('compare', '<='); 
$query->set('type', 'numeric');
```

But when i'm printing out the last query it's returning the following:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'salary_max' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '36000'
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What about modifying the meta_query argument. add this code in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts');
function my_get_posts($query) {
    if( get_query_var('slide') ) {
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'salary_max',
                'value'   => get_query_var('slide'),
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type'    => 'numeric'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}
```